# Enabling Simultaneous Interaction with Code and Video at same window

Tags: websocket, video-streaming, real-time, interactive, code-editor

I'm intrigued by the user experience in interactive coding tutorials, such as **Scrimba**, where learners can interact with both the video lessons and the code editor simultaneously. I'm eager to learn about the technical implementation that allows users to engage with both components seamlessly.

Specifically, I'm curious about:

- How is user interaction designed to work in a way that allows learners to watch video lessons and manipulate code in real-time?
- What technologies or frameworks enable the synchronization of video playback and code editing so that users can pause the video, make code changes, and see the immediate results on top of video?
- Are there any strategies or libraries commonly used to handle user input events effectively, ensuring that the video and code editor remain responsive and synchronized?

I would greatly appreciate insights or technical details on how this simultaneous interaction is achieved in interactive coding tutorials. Thank you for sharing your expertise!